# Naive Bayes classification in R with opposite result..

Tags: r, naivebayes

I am trying to do a Naive Bayes classification using R (Package e1071). Tried the usual Golf example and I am always getting opposite result.

**Scenario:**
If the weather is good, do I play Golf 'Yes' or 'No'?  Very straightforward instance.

Created a training dataset (df) and as per the training dataset, i am expecting the result as 'Yes' for 'Good' weather but its giving me a 'No'.

```
[1] No
Levels: No Yes
```

Any reason why is it happening this way? Is my understanding wrong or am i doing something wrong?

All supports are much appreciated..

Cheers..!

```
weather <- c("Good", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Bad","Good")
golf <- c("Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","Yes")
df <- data.frame(weather, golf) #Training dataset

df[] <- lapply(df, factor) #changing df to factor variables

df_new <- data.frame(weather = "Good") #Test dataset

library(e1071)
model <- naiveBayes(golf ~.,data=df)
predict(model, df_new, type ="class")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because factor encoding can be misleading. Indeed, if you do not make sure that factors in `df` and `df_new` are encoded the same way, you will get (seemingly) absurd results compared to what you see.

Take a look at the integer encoding of `df`

```
print(df$weather)
Good Good Good Bad  Bad  Good
print(as.integer(df$weather))
2 2 2 1 1 2
```

And compare it to the encoding of `df_new`

```
print(df_new$weather)
Good
print(as.integer(df_new$weather))
1
```

`Good` has been mapped to `1` in `df_new`, while `1` corresponds to `Bad` in `df`. So when you are applying your model, your are asking for a prediction based on a `Bad` weather.

You need to set the factors of `df_new` the same way they are encoded in `df`

```
df_new <- data.frame(weather = "Good") #Test dataset
df_new$weather <- factor(df_new$weather, levels(df$weather))
```

Comment: Wow.. this works like a charm with factor levels.. I have been reading all the theorems and do the searching for more than 3 weeks now..

Answer (score 1):

Its a problem with factor levels: your test data  doesn't have the correct levels. Some sample code should make it clear:

```r
weather <- c("Good", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Bad","Good")
golf <- c("Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","Yes")
df <- data.frame(weather, golf) #Training dataset

df[] <- lapply(df, factor) #changing df to factor variables
```

Here are now three ways to create the sample data, 2 work by specifying a comparable factor:

```r
df_new <- data.frame(weather = "Good")
df_new1 <- data.frame(weather = df$weather[nrow(df)]) 
df_new2 <- data.frame(weather = factor("Good", levels = levels(df$weather)))

library(e1071)
model <- naiveBayes(golf ~.,data=df)
predict(model, df_new, type ="class")
#> [1] No
#> Levels: No Yes
```

Predict works as expected on the factor variables

```r
predict(model, df_new1)
#> [1] Yes
#> Levels: No Yes

predict(model, df_new2)
#> [1] Yes
#> Levels: No Yes
```

And we can see the levels are off on the original

```r
lapply(c(df_new, df_new1, df_new2), levels)
#> $weather
#> [1] "Good"
#> 
#> $weather
#> [1] "Bad"  "Good"
#> 
#> $weather
#> [1] "Bad"  "Good"
```